# How to extract data out of JSON const in React native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I have a function that retrieves the location data in JSON from the Google Location Services API and store data into `location` const. The data it retrieves as follows :

```
{
  "mocked":false,
  "timestamp":11507048000,
  "coords":{
    "speed":0,
    "heading":0,
    "accuracy":52.086999893188477,
    "altitude":3,
    "longitude":-51.084,
    "latitude":14.183
  }
}
```

So I want basically to access and extract the data inside. For instance, get the latitude value and assign it to a variable.

Thanks in advance.

**findCoordinates function :**

```
findCoordinates = () => {
  if (!this.state.locationPermission) {
    this.state.locationPermission = requestLocationPermission();
  }
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    position => {
      const location = JSON.stringify(position);
      this.setState({ location });
    },
    error => {
      Alert.alert(error.message);
    },
    {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 20000,
      maximumAge: 1000
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: undefined result !

Comment: var data = this.state.location.coords.latitude?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following Code I set anew object in the state

```
 get_Lat_User() {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
                var longi = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)
                var initialRegion = {
                    latitude: lat,
                    longitude: longi,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.01 * ASPECT_RATIO,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.01
                }
                console.log("position", position)
                this.setState({ my_region: initialRegion })

            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error.message);



            },
            { enableHighAccuracy: false, showLocationDialog: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside callback of setstate, try this

```
 this.setState({ location },() =>{ 
      var data = this.state.location.coords.latitude;
      console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.location.coords.latitude')

Comment: what does position in your callback return?

Answer (score 0):

Your code `this.setState({ location });`  will destructure the object, so to access the e.g. `timestamp`, you'd need to call `this.state.timestamp`

If you wish to save the location as a separate property, use:

```
this.setState({ location: location });
```

This way you can call `this.state.location.<property>`

To keep in mind, setState() is an asynchronous function, so you might not be able to use the location immediately unless you do:

```
const loc;

this.setState({location:location}, () => {
  loc = this.state.location
});
```